# Stack Overflow Careers thinks my CV is missing some key information

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I got an email from "Stack Overflow Careers":

> Your job search status is open, but not actively looking, but it looks like your CV is missing some key information. Complete the following fields in order to receive better matches:
>   Add at least one complete record of work experience or education

However, I think I have added a complete record of work experience, so what is missing?

Comment: I recall something mentioned that to be considered "complete" it needed to have some minimum amount of content. Is your job description particularly short?

Comment: @TZHX Yes, but I have something in every field. It should be enough.

Comment: Then ignore the advice given by the Careers team.

Comment: Ok, so I've been away from Meta for a while, but do we not link public profiles to CVs in any way publicly yet? Are careers profiles *still* given "unique" status where only prospective employers can access? I'd like to help here but can't find an obvious link to view or indeed 'help'.

Comment: @nickhar It's a setting that every individual user can set. I believe that it's private by default.

Answer (score 11):

This is certainly something could certainly use more clarification in the UI, but your work entry does not meet the Responsibilities length requirement of at least 150 characters.

[image: Responsibilities text length UI feedback]

The other criteria are having at least two tags, some timeframe info, and company name.

Comment: Isn't that maximum allowed length?

Comment: Please allow shorter length. I am not a novelist.

Comment: @jarno makes a very good point. To me, that looks like 150 characters is the *maximum*, not the minimum. It should say "104 more characters to go..." like in the comment box.

Comment: @jarno: Don't number them, but give all of your responsiibilities a GUID. Not only does that get you over the 150 characters limit, it also shows that you're familiar with all the new database fads.

Comment: @jarno a reasonable person would assume so! :) Thanks for pointing that out - I'll look into making the character count feedback more clear.

Comment: @jarno sorry I'm not clear on your second request. You are already allowed to enter as many or as few characters as you want in this field. With less than 150 chars, you can still share your CV publicly and use it to apply to jobs. 150 char is required only for CVs to be indexed and searchable in our CV database, ensuring there is enough info for employers to decide whether to message a dev. Less than 150 chars risks wasting the dev's time, who will be more likely to get irrelevant messages from employers looking for experience/skills they don't have. Do you find this unreasonable?

Comment: @G-Wiz - Whilst it might not be an unreasonable request do you think ALL of those details are known when someone is filling this stuff out?  There is too many "internal" aspects here for a plain old user to understand.  This to me is a clear sign that something isn't right...

Comment: Or to put it another way, it might be a reasonable *request*, but if the UI doesn't actually present that request, "please write at least 150 characters, to give our search algorithm something to chew on and prevent false results that waste your time", then what matters is whether or not it's a reasonable *expectation* for people to figure all that out :-) Even once you fix the wording of the character counter, the request is "write at least 150 characters", which is a somewhat less reasonable request than, "write at least 150 characters, for a good reason that I will now explain..."

Comment: @SteveJessop et al. There's now a feature request to change the character count on this field; hop on over there if you want to give it an upvote or have more to say http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318524/fix-character-count-display-for-work-entries-with-cv