# Fix character count display for work entries with CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

Prompted by [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318506/512728):

The counter at the top right indicates a character count relative to a required minimum.

[image]

This is uncommon UI design. An indication *x/y characters* usually indicates that you have typed X characters of a maximum limit Y.

Please change that text/counter combo.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We'll be incorporating the same character counter behavior as used for Q&A comments shortly.